# Prometheus topk middle ranking

Tags: rank

How does Prometheus use the function to query the middle ranking? For example, I use TOPK to query the top 100, but I want to query 50-100. What should I do？

want to query 50-100

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@** modifier to rank range data with offset which queries in custom range with *topk*(),  alike **offset** modifier.

*For more info visit doc:*

[Prometheus - @ Modifier](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/02/18/introducing-the-@-modifier/)

[Querying with @ Modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier)